# what exactly does apt -get do in linux?

Tags: apt-get

I'm a beginner with Linux.  I have on numerous occasions used apt-get, but my question is what exactly does it do?  If I'm using apt-get "some random application", what exactly is this doing?  I guess I'm confused where it's getting the application to install or where its pulling from..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, apt-get calls the repositories, some sort of lists of supported programs (and links where to download it from) . You can add repositories, this extends the list of programs you can install via 'apt-get'. That's the impression i've got using it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the man page `$ man apt-get`.  It should answer most of your questions.

Comment: Where exactly is this list of repositories located?